# Laravel Resource collection showing null field

Tags: laravel, api, eloquent, collections, resources

I'm developing an API with Laravel. In one of the endpoint I'm accessing, some fields are showing a null value, but it should have some information.

Note the "addicionais_descricao" and "valor" fields, both always come with null values when I include them in the attributeitems array, but if I leave it at the initial level, the data is presented, but it doesn't solve my case, because I need this information with the attribute items:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbPgj.png)

This is where the endpoint calls, I make the query in the "Attribute" table, which has a relationship with the "Attributeitems" table, while the "attributeitems" table is linked to "Attribute" and "product".

```
public function show($id)
{

    $atributos = Atributo::query('atributo')
        ->select(
            'atributo.id',
            'atributo.atrdescricao',
            'atributoitens.atributo_id',
            'atributoitens.produto_id',
            'produto.prodescricao',
            'produto.provalor'
        )

        ->leftJoin('atributoitens', 'atributo.id', '=', 'atributoitens.atributo_id')
        ->leftJoin('produto', 'produto.id', '=', 'atributoitens.produto_id')
        ->where('atributo.id', '=', $id)

        ->get()->unique('id');

    return AtributoResource::collection($atributos);
}
```

Resource Atributo:

```
    public function toArray($request)
{
    
    return [            
        'id' => $this->id,
        'descricao' => $this->atrdescricao, 
         'atributoitens' => AtributoitensResource::collection($this->atributoitens),
    ];
}
```

Resource Atributo Itens:

```
public function toArray($request)
{        
    
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'atributo' => $this->atributo_id,
        'produtos' => $this->produto_id,            
        'adicionais_descricao' => $this->prodescricao,
        'valor' => $this->provalor            
        
    ];
}
```

What is the correct procedure for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Take this example as a reference :

**Controller**

```
$data = $shop->products()
        ->whereStatus(true)
        ->where('product_shop.active', true)
        ->where('product_shop.quantity', '>=', $this->min_product_qty)
        ->paginate(50);

return (new ProductCollection($data))
    ->response()
    ->setStatusCode(200);
```

**ProductCollection**

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data' => $this->collection
                      ->map(function($product) use ($request) {
                            return (new ProductResource($product))->toArray($request);
                        }),
            'brand' => $this->when($request->brand, $request->brand)
        ];
    }
```

**ProductResource**

```
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'type' => 'product',
            'id' => (string) $this->id,

            'attributes' => [
                'uuid' => $this->uuid,
                'name' => $this->name,
                'slug' => $this->slug,
                'description' => $this->description,
                'thumb_path' => $this->thumb_path,
                'cover_path' => $this->cover_path,
            ],

            'relationships' => [
                'brand' => $this->brand 
            ]
        ];
    }
```

Comment: I tried to adapt your recommendation, but with no success. I'll show you my result.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help you do what you want. I cant exactly do it for you. by the way why you are not using Eloquent, something like
`Attribute::where(...)->with(['relation_1', 'products'])->get();`

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'attributes' => [...],
            'products' => $this->collection
                      ->map(function($this->product) use ($request) {
                            return (new ProductResource($product))->toArray($request);
                        }),
        ];
    }
```

Comment: I don't use it for lack of knowledge. But I tried to use making the "belongsToMany"  (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-table-structure) relationship. the result is great when I don't use AttributeResource::collection, but when I use some fields are null